# Flutter Error: no named parameter with the name "overflow"

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-packages, speed-dial

I am working on an app in flutter, and everything was working fine when suddenly one day when i tried to run the app it get me this error:

```
/C:/sdk%20Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_speed_dial-1.2.5/lib/src/speed_dial.dart:249:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'overflow'.
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      ^^^^^^^^

/C:/sdk%20Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart:3273:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  Stack({
  ^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\sdk Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\sdk Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

I'm using the flutter_speed_dial: ^1.2.5 package
(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial) and
i was looking in some forums but i couldn't solve this issue yet.

This is some part of the code:

```
floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        
        marginRight: 18,
        marginBottom: 20,
        child: Image.asset("Imagenes/Teams/team1_logo.png"),
        closeManually: false,
        curve: Curves.bounceIn,
        overlayColor: Colors.black,
        overlayOpacity: 0.5,
        onOpen: () => print('OPENING DIAL'),
        onClose: () => print('DIAL CLOSED'),
        tooltip: 'Speed Dial',
        heroTag: 'speed-dial-hero-tag',
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
        elevation: 8.0,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
              child: FittedBox(
                  child: Image.asset(
                "Imagenes/Teams/team2_logo.png",
                width: 2,
                height: 2,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              )),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              label: 'Vikingos',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
              onTap: () {
                /* // variables para mover el equipo principal al seleccionar uno del floating button
                team_wait = team_selected;
                team_selected = team_child1;
                team_child1 = team_wait;
                print(team_selected);
                print(team_child1);*/
              }),
          SpeedDialChild(
            child: FittedBox(
                child: Image.asset(
              "Imagenes/Teams/team3_logo.png",
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            )),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            label: 'Aguilas',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            onTap: () => print('SECOND CHILD'),
          ),
          SpeedDialChild(
            child: Image.asset("Imagenes/Teams/team4_logo.png"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[700],
            label: 'Inter',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            onTap: () => print('THIRD CHILD'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.252, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale es-MX)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0-10.0.pre.252 at C:\sdk Flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision 78929661fb (67 minutes ago), 2020-09-18 08:08:30 -0700
    • Engine revision 2abe69c608
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-136.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\msaldivar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 44.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.49.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\msaldivar\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.14.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
exit code 0
```

Comment: This is an issue with the package. Someone has already filed an issue. There isn't much we can do for this here.

Answer (score 4):

You should also check the PR's of the library ;). [This one](https://github.com/darioielardi/flutter_speed_dial/pull/83) fixes the problem. You can check the [commits](https://github.com/darioielardi/flutter_speed_dial/pull/83/commits) and change your code in your side. Or maybe wait some days, hours for the merge.

If you are really in need, you can fork the library, but for now just comment the code that references to it until the fix is merged

Answer (score 3):

This error is usually caused by outdated(out-version) third party packages, the simplest solution is:

go to `puspec.yaml` and then remove all the third-party packages (remember which packages you are using) run "`flutter pub get`", then go to terminal do "`flutter Clean`" Then add all the packages with their latest version run "`flutter pub get`".

If the issue persists then try removing the only package that is responsible for the problem. in my case curvedNavigationBar was the problematic one, I removed the package then the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same error. It was occurred due to an external package (in my case it was '*dropdown field*'). The error caused was due to *autvalidate: false*, like the below snippet.

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dropdownfield-1.0.3/lib/dropdownfield.dart:88:11: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
     autovalidate: false,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   Unhandled exception:
```

to solve this simply go to the documentation of the package/dependency that you are using, and comment the field that cause the error. like this,

```
super(
      key: key,
     // autovalidate: false,
      initialValue: controller != null ? controller.text : (value ?? ''),
      onSaved: setter,
```

Then run your app again. I hope it will solve your problem.
If it is helpful then plz accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with this kind of problem. After updating the flutter sdk, my problem was solved. Update your flutter sdk, it may work.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTQZI.jpg.

It was a peculiar problem. All you need to do is upgrade your flutter SDK so that you can resolve it. In my case, I was not able to use [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMpbP.png)-party package StyledText when I updated my SDK. The problem is resolved.